# Why does std::set::insert() call operator<() with bad parameter

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, std, stdset

I need help to understand why `std::set<T>::insert(T)` is calling `operator<(const T&, const T&)` with an invalid reference as its second parameter, creating a segfault upon my first insertion.

Here is the class whose objects I want to insert in a set:

```
/**
 * A CPC category.
 */
class Category {

  private:
    char m_section;
    int  m_class;
    char m_subclass;
    int  m_group;
    int  m_subgroup;

  public:
    Category();
    Category(char t_section, int t_class, char t_subclass, int t_group,
             int t_subgroup);
    char get_section() const;
    int  get_class() const;
    char get_subclass() const;
    int  get_group() const;
    int  get_subgroup() const;

};
```

Here is my `operator<` (sorry, not the cleanest method ever):

```
/**
 * Obeys simple lexical order. A smaller-than operator for Category is
 * required to allow objects to be placed in an std::set.
 */
bool operator<(const Category& cat1, const Category& cat2)
{
    return (cat1.get_section() == cat2.get_section() ?
                cat1.get_class() == cat2.get_class() ?
                    cat1.get_subclass() == cat2.get_subclass() ?
                        cat1.get_group() == cat2.get_group() ?
                            cat1.get_subgroup() == cat2.get_subgroup() ?
                                true :
                                cat1.get_subgroup() < cat2.get_subgroup() :
                            cat1.get_group() < cat2.get_group() :
                        cat1.get_subclass() < cat2.get_subclass() :
                    cat1.get_class() < cat2.get_class() :
                cat1.get_section() < cat2.get_section());
}
```

And here is the code creating the set:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, CategorySet& cs)
{
    std::set<Category>* cats;
    Category cat;
    while (is >> cat) {
        cats->insert(cat);
    }   
    cs = CategorySet{ cats };
    return is;
}
```

I put a breakpoint just before `cats->insert(cat);`:

```
Breakpoint 1, InnovationModelling::operator>> (is=..., cs=...) at lib/PatentData.cpp:126
126         cats->insert(cat);
(gdb) p *cats
$9 = std::set with 0 elements
(gdb) p cat
$1 = {m_section = 65 'A', m_class = 1, m_subclass = 65 'A', m_group = 1, m_subgroup = 0}
(gdb) ptype cat
type = class InnovationModelling::Category {
  private:
    char m_section;
    int m_class;
    char m_subclass;
    int m_group;
    int m_subgroup;

  public:
    Category(void);
    Category(char, int, char, int, int);
    char get_section(void) const;
    int get_class(void) const;
    char get_subclass(void) const;
    int get_group(void) const;
    int get_subgroup(void) const;
}
```

(The `$9` above is because I forgot to show that the set is empty at this point so I ran the program a second time.)

Then I stepped through `std::set`'s stuff until it calls `operator()`, which is not overloaded:

```
(gdb) s
std::less<InnovationModelling::Category>::operator() (this=0x5555555993c0 <std::cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4>, __x=..., __y=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/stl_function.h:386
386       { return __x < __y; }
(gdb) p __x
$2 = (const InnovationModelling::Category &) @0x7fffffffd3b0: {m_section = 65 'A', m_class = 1, m_subclass = 65 'A', m_group = 1, 
  m_subgroup = 0}
(gdb) p __y
$3 = (const InnovationModelling::Category &) <error reading variable>
```

And sure enough, `operator<` gets called with this invalid reference and therefore `get_section()` eventually gets called on it and segfaults:

```
(gdb) s
InnovationModelling::Category::get_section (this=0x26) at lib/PatentData.cpp:187
187     return m_section;
(gdb) p this
$7 = (const InnovationModelling::Category * const) 0x26
(gdb) p *this
Cannot access memory at address 0x26
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555568412 in InnovationModelling::Category::get_section (this=0x26) at lib/PatentData.cpp:187
```

I'm sorry if it's obvious what `std::set::insert()` is doing, but I'm very much a beginner in C++, and I can't even wrap my head around the fact that it feels the need to call `operator<()` at all to insert something in an empty set.

Comment: I'm going to guess there's something wrong with your `operator<`, most likely that it does not implement strict weak ordering correctly. It's also pretty much unreadable. Consider `return std::tie(cat1.a, cat1.b, etc) < std::tie(cat2.a, cat2.b, etc)` instead.

Comment: The `operator>>()` creates an uninitialised pointer (`cats`) and repeatedly dereferences it.   That gives undefined behaviour.    It needs to be initialised to point at a valid object BEFORE dereferencing it.    Once the behaviour of your program is undefined, all bets are off.    Including the illusion you are seeing of some other function in `std::set` misbehaving.

Comment: Your `operator <` returns true when the categories are equal. This is a bug. Though, probably not what causes the issue.

Comment: @Peter It's probably not an illusion as that comparator is crazy, but you're right too

Comment: Thank you all. I see now that my question will not be helpful to others. Should I keep it nonetheless or delete it? I have reimplemented these classes without pointers and it has fixed this issue and others I was having as well. I am not sure why I chose to implement a preorder in `operator<`, but I can see why it doesn't work with the semantics of `<` and how it could mess with `std::set`, so I fixed that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And here is the code creating the set:

'Fraid not.

You created a pointer-to-set, but it doesn't actually point to any set; it's just an uninitialised pointer.

You could use `new` to dynamically allocate a set, but don't do that unless you have to. In fact, don't use pointers unless you have to. Your needs here will be driven by `CategorySet` (which we know nothing about), but if you can just make your set a nice local variable, life will be much easier.